# How do I separate my JavaScript objects into multiple files

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to separate my JavaScript into nice libraries. I have 2 companies under the net top-level-domain (net.foxbomb and net.matogen)

```
var net = {
    foxbomb : {
        'MyObject' : function() {
            console.log ("FoxBomb")
        }
    }
}
```

```
var net = {
    matogen : {
        'MyObject' : function() {
            console.log ("Matogen");
        }
    }
}
```

```
var f = new net.foxbomb.MyObject();
var m = new net.matogen.MyObject();
```

Of course, I've just defined two nets - which doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the concept of "packages," e.g. see http://npmjs.org. Editing for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File 1:

```
var net = net || {};

net.foxbomb = {

  // ...

};
```

File 2:

```
var net = net || {};

net.matogen = {

  // ...

};
```

Le fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q8TnL/1/

Comment: I'm assuming you want to separate the scripts into different files. If I'm reading you wrong, let me know and I'll delete this.

Comment: I just tried an example with them both in the same file (they would typically be in different files), but it's not working :(

Comment: @MarkvanWyk is it `org.foxbomb` or `net.foxbomb`?

Comment: Apologies GGG, I made a typo. Works 100%. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

Separate the properties by a comma:

```
var net = {
    foxbomb : {
        'MyObject' : function() {
            console.log ("FoxBomb")
        }
    }, // <-- Comma
    matogen : {
        'MyObject' : function() {
            console.log ("Matogen");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that they're in different JavaScript files.